# Find And replace Specific part in notepad ++

Tags: php, notepad++

I have a file where i have to find and replace a  string with specific string multiple times. but problem is some specific part of string is different every time it matches.

Suppose my String are:

```
$mail = Input::get('email');

$phone = Input::get('phone');
```

So I have to replace some part of string like

"`Input::get(`"

To

" `htmlspecialchars(trim(Input::get('email')))`" .

So email or phone part will be dynamic i don't want to replace that.

How can I do that . Any help would be highly Appreciated.

Comment: You can do that with `CTRL + F` to find `Then` `CTRL+R` to `Replace` And proceed to Replace all

Comment: Actaully i dont want to replace email or phone word. I just want to make these word regular expression as it should be same as it was

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a way to do the job:

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `(Input::get\('.+?'\));`
- Replace with: `htmlspecialchars\(trim\($1\)\);`
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
(               : start group 1
  Input::get\(' : literally (NB parenthesis must be escaped)
    .+?         : one or more anycharacter, not greedy
  '\)           : literally
);              : end group 1 and semi colon
```

In the replacement part, parenthesis must be escaped in Npp

Comment: Maybe you can add a short explanation as a bonus. +1 for the usage of <kbd> and markup

Answer (score 0):

You don't even need a regex for that.

Simply replace 'Input::get(' by 'htmlspecialchars(trim(Input::get('

That should keep the rest intact. And do a global replace..

Comment: What about the closing parenthesis?

Comment: Do another search and replace on both:
email') and phone') and replace them with 
email'))) and phone'))) 

This is turning into something relatively ugly, and it is useful to start learning regexes. But in this specific case I still think that 2-3 global search and replaces are a lot quicker than trying to come up with a suitable regex (unless you're experienced at doing this)